# function within f-string is returning the function outside the string, and returning None inside the string

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to python and trying to do an f-string as follows:

```
next_patient = East_Room.get_highest_priority()
print(f"The next patient is {next_patient.display_symptoms()} please")
```

Where East_Room is an instance of a Class and get_highest_priority is a method within the class to display a patient with the highest integer for the 'severity' attribute as follows:

```
def get_highest_priority(self):
    tmp_priority_patient = None
    current_size = self.SLL_waiting_list.size()     
    counter = 1
    while counter <= current_size:
        tmp_node = self.SLL_waiting_list.get_node(counter)
        tmp_patient = tmp_node.get_obj()
        if tmp_priority_patient == None:
            tmp_priority_patient = tmp_patient
        else:
            if tmp_patient.severity > tmp_priority_patient.severity:
                tmp_priority_patient = tmp_patient
        counter = counter + 1
    return tmp_priority_patient

def display_symptoms(self):
print(f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}:{self.symptoms}")
```

This is the output:

Conor : Naseau

The next patient is None please

I know that this method works as it works perfectly if I call it without the f-string. thanks for you help!

Comment: The use of a `while` loop in this case is non-pythonic. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Could you show us the `display_symptoms` function? It looks like the problem comes from there.

Comment: What is `SLL_waiting_list`? That seems like a candidate to make into an iterator, rather than requiring a `get_node` function to retrieve elements explicitly. For that matter, you might want to look at the documentation for the `heapq` module to see how to implement a priority queue.

Comment: "I know that this method works as it works perfectly if I call it without the f-string". Convince us. It's not obvious why that should be the case.

Comment: @AdamBoinet thanks for looking at this, here you go:

    def display_symptoms(self):
        print(f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}: {self.symptoms}")

Comment: @chepner sorry if I wasn't clear, by 'method' I meant the python method display_symptoms as this works when its standalone. Obviously, my whole method here isn't working

Comment: We have only your word that it works. Nothing you've shown here suggests that it should. We need a [mcve].

Comment: @dylan193 please edit your question to add the code of `display_symptoms`

Comment: functions/methods without and explicit return value return None by default

Comment: @AdamBoinet yes perfect that's working now. Thank you! Just wondering, why was the function working outside of the f-string? Because it was printing it out but not returning a value?

Comment: @chepner sorry that just seems like a lot of work just to prove i'm not lying when i have no reason to lie here

Comment: Your function did *not* work as you claimed it did, which is why we need reproducible samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display_symptoms` only prints information but doesn't return anything.

In Python, function that don't return anything return `None`, hence the output you got: *"The next patient is None please"*

If you also want the function to return this string, you have to explicitly return it:

```py
def display_symptoms(self):
    print(f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}: {self.symptoms}")
    return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}: {self.symptoms}"
```

An even better way to do it would be to make it a property:

```py
@property
def display_symptoms(self):
    return f"{self.firstname} {self.lastname}: {self.symptoms}"
```